# How to display number one by one from number string using php?

Tags: php, html

Below code using in my website for visitor counter,so how can i display if number string is 0541000 suing php, I want below result using php

```
   <ul class="visiter-number">
      <li>0</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>0</li>
      <li>0</li>
      <li>0</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$input = '0541000';

echo '<ul class="visiter-number">';
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++) {
  echo '<li>' .  $input[$i] . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 1):

try this-

```
<ul class="visiter-number">
<?php

$word = '0541000';
$myword = str_split($word);
foreach ($myword as $val) {
    echo "<li>" . $val . "</li>";
}

?>
</ul>
```

Comment: in double quotes (`"`) you can use variables without having to concatenate it with the dots.

Comment: @Jonan yess! i know. but, i usually prefer this way! Btw, you did the same too! :-)

Comment: Yes, I prefer single quotes over double - and you can't use variables within single quotes :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$numbers = '0541000';
$array = str_split($numbers);

echo '<ul class="visiter-number">';
foreach($array as $number){
    echo '<li>' . $number . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo   '<ul class="visiter-number"><li>'
     . implode('</li><li>', str_split('0541000'))
     . '</li></ul>';
```

in case, the string is not empty.